# Anime where characters fight each other for book pages that contain memories

Tags: story-identification, anime

Characters have to fight each other in order to collect pages of a book. But whenever that pages of the book from their memories are taken so are the memories that they have with their beloved ones.

- Whenever the girl loses, the other girl would turn their weapon/their weapon is massive key-shaped object. They will insert the key into the loser’s chest to open their memories and cruelly taking the pages out of their memories.

I can remember the girls are dressed in medieval kind of puffy dresses.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made? Also, did you watch it on TV or online? If on TV, then on which channel and in which country?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be *[Key Princess Story: Eternal Alice Rondo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kagihime_Monogatari_Eiky%C5%AB_Alice_Rondo)* (*Kagihime Monogatari Eikyū Alice Rondo*)?

> The story revolves around the lead of the story, Kirihara Aruto. It
> begins one night when Aruto is awake writing his own copy of The
> Endless Alice. Suddenly he sees a girl leaping through the night sky.
> Believing her to be the Alice he writes about, he leaves his house and
> follows her to a library.
>
> He sees her fighting with another girl, who is defeated. The former
> then steals the latter's story and disappears. The next day, she
> reveals herself as Arisugawa Arisu, the female lead of the story. **She
> then explains that she is an Alice User, capable of transforming into
> a kemonomimi bunny girl that uses a key in fights against other Alice
> Users. The keys are used to unlock the stories in other Alice Users's
> hearts.** She explains that if a girl loses her story that she can no
> longer be an Alice User; the overall goal of an Alice User is to
> defeat all others and finish the Endless Alice. The one who does so
> will be granted a wish.